# Change Windows 10 shortcut for changing workspace

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, workspace

In Windows 10 there is a keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd>
that changes between workspaces. 
It works very well and fast when is it used when using a touchpad. 
But, in a case when someone is a using a mouse, it is not very comfortable to switch between workspaces (always need to move right hand between mouse and keyboard arrows).

I think the best solution will be to allow user to switch between workspaces with combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+[Left mouse click] / [Right mouse click].

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) program and add any behivor keys that you want
[example script for you](https://github.com/pmb6tz/windows-desktop-switcher)